# Need reload after save product in back office prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop-1.7

```
public function hookActionObjectProductUpdateAfter($data){
    // need reload page
}
```

Please help me with the reload page after saving the product.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to recharge?
Otherwise you have to try with : `Tools::redirect($url);`

Regards

Comment: No, it's not working any hook for change JS or customize response? https://nimb.ws/vVUm6x

Comment: Ok in hook action it's not possible.

Comment: then what way is possible